# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "org-appextension-feature-password-management://" - error: "(null)" (PayPal)

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I dont understand why I have this error. "org-appextension-feature-password-management" is in the Property List. [MyPlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gphcx.png)

Its just a warning but it freezes the app. I tried all environnements (Production, NoNetwork, Sandbox...), but the result is the same. 
Can you help me please ? 
Regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. There is a conflict between PayPal SDK and the pod IQKeyboardManager. So I removed it, and it works perfectly.